# Spring boot 3 Get Request Object anywhere in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How can I do something similar to Spring boot 2, in Spring boot 3 and the new Spring Webflux / reactor

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
public class ReactiveRequestContextFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(ReactiveRequestContextHolder.CONTEXT_KEY, request));
    }
}
```

```
public class ReactiveRequestContextHolder {
    public static final Class<ServerHttpRequest> CONTEXT_KEY = ServerHttpRequest.class;

    public static Mono<ServerHttpRequest> getRequest() {
        return Mono.subscriberContext()
                .map(ctx -> ctx.get(CONTEXT_KEY));
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class GetRequestController {

    @RequestMapping("/request")
    public Mono<String> getRequest() {
        return ReactiveRequestContextHolder.getRequest()
                .map(request -> request.getHeaders().getFirst("user"));
    }
}
```

How can I do something similar to Spring boot 2, in Spring boot 3 and the new Spring Webflux / reactor. A shared reactive context.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `subscriberContext()` methods were deprecated and removed in 3.5.0

You should use `contextWrite()` and `deferContextual()` instead.

Declare a filter bean like this:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ReactiveRequestContextFilter implements WebFilter, Ordered {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<Void> filter(@NonNull ServerWebExchange exchange, @NonNull WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                    .contextWrite(context -> context.put(ReactiveRequestContextHolder.CONTEXT_KEY, request));
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You should consider `Ordered` interface and specify -1 value to ensure your filter is executed as soon as possible in your webfilter chain.

Your ReactiveRequestContextHolder:

```java
public class ReactiveRequestContextHolder {

    public static final Class<ServerHttpRequest> CONTEXT_KEY = ServerHttpRequest.class;

    public static Mono<ServerHttpRequest> getRequest() {
        return Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.just(contextView.get(CONTEXT_KEY)));
    }
}
```

And your controller, for example:

```java
@GetMapping
public Mono<String> test() {
   return ReactiveRequestContextHolder.getRequest()
           .map(ServerHttpRequest::getId);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the ReactiveRequestContextHolder.getRequest() throws exception that the context is empty .

Comment: Also have same error, i saw that there are multiple Contex classes, and in our example it searched in Contex0 but put on Context1

Comment: I edited my answer, please take a look.